# Why are XML DataTemplates ignored?

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding

In the following sample, the DataTemplate is ignored by WPF.

Why is this?

```
<Window x:Class="TestXmlNonBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Xml="clr-namespace:System.Xml;assembly=System.Xml">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Xml:XmlDocument}">
        <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Xml:XmlDocument></Xml:XmlDocument>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's a good question; I don't know why it's been downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with binding, not template selection.

If you look at the documentation for `Binding.XPath`, you'll see that when the binding source is XML data (i.e. an `XmlDocument` or `XmlNode`) the `XPath` property is used, rather than the `Path` property, to find the property on the data source.

I suspect that what's happening here is that the `Binding` is not returning an `XmlDocument`.  The binding sees that the source object is an `XmlDocument`, and it calls `SelectNodes` on it, passing in the value of the `XPath` property as an argument.  That's null (or maybe an empty string), and so `SelectNodes` doesn't return anything.

Comment: That is not correct, you can check the property, it is indeed the whole XmlDocument, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`DataTemplates` have a special functionality to deal with XML, if there is XML-data the [`DataType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) is interpreted as the name of the XML-element that should be templated:

> If the template is intended for object data, this property contains the type name of the data object (as a string). To refer to the type name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension. If the template is intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name. See the documentation remarks for details about specifying a non-default namespace for the XML element.