# DataTemplate implicitly mapped to System.Xml.XmlDocument isn't being recognised

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I am trying to create my own control to view XmlDocuments.

My understanding of WPF is that I can create a DataTemplate that's implicitly mapped to a certain type.

Then, if I assign an object of this type to a ContentPresenter, it will automatically selected the appropriate DataTemplate.

So why isn't this 15-line piece of XAML working?

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataTemplates.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:systemXml="clr-namespace:System.Xml;assembly=System.Xml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type systemXml:XmlDocument}"> 
            <TextBlock Text="Look! An xml document!" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <systemXml:XmlDocument x:Key="TokenXmlDocument" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TokenXmlDocument}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ContentPresenter's content is an XmlDocument, so it should utilise the data template I've created for it. I should see the text "Look! An xml document!".

Instead I see an empty window.

---

**Later Edit**: Someone was having a similar problem here: [Why are XML DataTemplates ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747115/why-are-xml-datatemplates-ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Strange! Really.

And this works!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:sysxml="clr-namespace:System.Xml;assembly=System.Xml"
    Title="Window2" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sysxml:XmlDocument}">
        <TextBlock Text="Look! A system Xml!" />
     </DataTemplate>
     <local:LocalXmlDocument x:Key="LocalXmlDocument" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel x:Name="Panel">
     <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource LocalXmlDocument}"  />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and in code behind...

```
public class LocalXmlDocument : XmlDocument
{
}
```

Strange unexplained world of WPF!

Comment: Unexplained? People just do not [look stuff up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) enough.

Answer (score 0):

[F1:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx)

> If the template is intended for object data, this property contains
>   the type name of the data object (as a string). To refer to the type
>   name of the class, use the x:Type Markup Extension. If the template is
>   intended for XML data, this property contains the XML element name.
>   See the documentation remarks for details about specifying a
>   non-default namespace for the XML element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead "{x:Type sysxml:XmlDocument}" use "#document"